# Setting a 32-bit sprite to 50% opacity in SDL/Pascal?

Tags: graphics, sdl, freepascal

I'm working on someone else's game and am not familiar with SDL or Pascal. What I am trying to do is upgrade the game graphics from 8 bits to 32 bits. So far it is going well, except for the following procedure:

```
    SDL_SetAlpha( Spr^.Img , SDL_SRCAlpha , Alpha_Level );
    DrawAnimImage( Spr^.Img , Spr^.W , Spr^.H , Frame , MyDest );
    SDL_SetAlpha( Spr^.Img , SDL_SRCAlpha , SDL_Alpha_Opaque );
```

This code is supposed to change the opacity of a sprite to 50% when your character walks near it. It works well with 8 and probably 24 bit images, but not with 32 bit images. How can I rewrite this code to handle 32 bit images with alpha channels?

This old blog article sort of describes what I need to do, but I am a noob and don't understand all of it.

http://www.sdltutorials.com/the-ins-and-outs-and-overlays-of-alpha-blending

It mentions a library called Sprig. Is this my only choice on how to proceed? How do I use it? Does it work with Pascal programs?

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't something you easily do since you'll have to manually recalculate srcsurface alpha (need to save previous alpha first to restore it later). It is not something a begineer would do (nothing too hard here, but requires working with pixels in raw memory and bitmasks). However, why you're using RGBA in first place if initial graphics didn't have an alpha channel?

Comment: I recreated all the graphics from scratch in 32-bit.

Comment: What about the Sprig library I mentioned?